# Git Push Remote Modified files

Tags: git

I'm using git server on a development environment to essentially be the "ftp" / handler via SSH.

I init'd git on the remote server via bare and pushed from local.  Once all settled I removed bare.  I then push remote latest batch = accepted.

On the remote server I run git status and see modified files.  How can it accept the changes with out having to reset or so?

Comment: What do you mean by "having to reset or so"?

Comment: @ThomasStringer i.e. git reset soft / hard; actually what's worked so far on remote server is git checkout -- .; but i don't want to do that every time

Comment: What do you mean by "accept the changes"?  Accept what changes?

Comment: Wait.  You're using Git as a way to deploy your code?  Is that where you're going with this?

Comment: @Makoto yup, thought I'd give it a shot.  At least for some DEV envs.

Comment: You generally want to avoid doing that for the very reason you're running into right now.  You don't describe how those files are being modified on the remote server though; could you elaborate?

Comment: @Makoto yeah that makes sense.  The experiment I wanted to attempt was a multi node applicant that I can easily push code (changes) to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach:

1. Keep a bare repository on the server, that you will push to
2. Create a clone on the server of the bare repository
3. Setup a post-receive hook on the bare repository, that will do a `git pull` on the clone after it receives new commits

With this setup, you can push revisions to the bare repository, and its clone will update itself. I wrote a [blog post](http://www.janosgyerik.com/deploying-new-releases-using-git-and-the-post-receive-hook/) on this with more details.